# RxJS の `flatMap` の挙動が直感と異なる

Tags: javascript, rx-javascript

以下のコードの出力なんですが、

```
var source = Rx.Observable
.range(1, 3)
.flatMap(function (v) {
    return Rx.Observable.range(1, 3);
})
.subscribe(function (v) {
    console.log(v)
});
```

下記になります。

```
1
2
1
3
2
1
3
2
3
```

ところが、私がイメージしていた結果は

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

[公式のドキュメント](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md)を見てもさっぱり分からないです。

なぜそうなるのか、何方か説明して頂けませんか？　ありがとうございます！

Comment: 結果から推測すると、flatMapに返された個々のObservable**内**での順序は保証しているけど、Observable**間**の順序は保証していない印象ですね。

Comment: RxJS ではなく、 RxJava を使うことがあるのですが RxJava の flatMap も順番が保証されないものになっており、大抵結果が順不同になります。 参考までに。

Answer (score 4):

この動きはflatMapによるものではなくて、Observable.rangeのスケジューラによるものですね。

Observable.rangeの中をみると、デフォルトでScheduler.currentThreadというスケジューラを利用しています。
期待の動作を得るためには、以下のようにScheduler.immediateを使って即時実行するとよいかと思います。

```
var source = Rx.Observable
.range(1, 3, Rx.Scheduler.immediate)
.flatMap(function (v) {
    return Rx.Observable.range(1, 3, Rx.Scheduler.immediate);
})
.subscribe(function (v) {
    console.log(v)
});
```

参考: 
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/schedulers/scheduler.md

Comment: ありがとうございます！なんとなく「Scheduler」が原因だということが分かりましたが、そもそも「Scheduler」って何なの？とドキュメントを眺めててずっと疑問に思ってました。貼り付けて頂いたページを見ても、「Scheduler」の説明が見当たらなく、あたかも「コールバック」のような一般的な概念として扱われているように見えます。私の無知で申し訳ありませんが、「Scheduler」とはRxJS固有の概念なのか？それとも一般的に知られているものなのでしょうか？

Comment: SchedulerはRx固有の概念ですね(RxJSだけでなくRx全般で使われています)
確かに参考リンクにはちゃんと説明書いてないですね。すみません…。
こちらはもう少し詳しいですがRxJSに限らない説明になっています。
http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html

Schedulerは簡単に言うと、登録したコールバック関数の実行タイミングを管理するためのクラスです。
immediateであれば即座に実行、currentThreadであれば一旦キューに登録してから順に実行、timeoutであればsetTimeoutに登録して実行という感じです。

Comment: うん…javascriptでマルチスレッドできないはずなのに、なぜ並び順が変わるんでしょう…？

Comment: [CurrentThreadSchedulerの実装](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/concurrency/currentthreadscheduler.js) を見てみるといいかもしれません。
JavaScriptではマルチスレッドはできませんが、CurrentThreadSchedulerでは、関数をいったんキューに登録しておいて、優先度の高いものをキューから取り出して実行するという実装になっています。
そのため、実行順序が変わってしまうことがあります。

一方ImmediateSchedulerはキューなどは使わずに即時実行しているので、直感的に分かりやすい動きになっているんじゃないかと思います。(元回答を少し修正しました。)

Comment: 度々ありがとうございます！！
所謂「優先度つきキュー」から取り出して実行しているということなんですね。ソースは何度も読んでみたのですが、さっぱりです…そもそもの使い方がある程度分からないと読みづらいのでしょうか？ここでいう「優先度」というのは何を基準に決まるんですか？それとも自分で決められるんですか！？

Comment: 実装をみてみると、実行までの待ち時間が小さいものが優先順位が高いようですね。
Rxでは時間を扱うので、スケジューラが必要になります。
Observable.rangeではスケジューラの存在する意味は分かりにくいと思いますが、例えば以下のようなコードではデータの流れる順番が変わるので、スケジューラがないとうまく動かないと思います。
var source = Rx.Observable
.range(1, 3)
.flatMap(function (v) {
    return Rx.Observable.return(v).delay(Math.random()*5000);
})
.subscribe(function (v) {
    console.log(v)
});

Comment: なるほど！書いて頂いたコード例がすごく分かりやすかったです。どうもありがとうございます！やはりコードが読めるようにならなければいけないのですね。コード読むのが大の苦手の私には何かアドバイスはないのでしょうかｗ

Comment: まぁ、慣れですかねｗ
RxJSは挙動を理解するのが難しいので、読んでわからなければブレイクポイント張りつつステップ実行してみるとよいと思います。